# How to get the contents between nested tags in java html parser?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jericho-html-parser

Eg. Consider the html 
 `<html>`
   `<body>`
     `<p> Hello <b> world </b> </p>`
    `</body>`
  `</html>`
how can i get the content "Hello" while parsing?
Please help me. I need it in java. I'm aware of few html parsers like jehrico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `handleText()` will give you that.

Comment: I couldn find tht method. With wat object can u call it??

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/DocumentParser.html